# mysqli result function

Tags: php, mysqli

So as we know there is no actual `mysqli result` as there is with `mysql` so I am in a bind. I did a quick search and found a function that would replicate the same effect, but it seems that it isn't working. I am not sure if I implemented it wrong or if the function is just no good.

This is the script

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['aname'] == NULL){
header("Location: index.php?au=login");
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    function email_result($res, $row, $field=0) {
        $res->data_seek($row);
        $datarow = $res->fetch_array();
        return $datarow[$field];
    }
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $subject = stripslashes($_POST['subject']);
        $message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);
    }
    else
    {
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
    }

    $result = $db->query("SELECT `email` FROM `members` WHERE `alert` = '1'");
    $num = $result->num_rows;
    $i=0;
    while($i < $num) 
    {
        $email = email_result($result,$i,"email");
        mail($email, $subject, $message, "From: ".$settings_info['website_name']." Admin<".$settings_info['admin_email'].">");
        echo "Email sent to: ".$email."<br />";
        header("Refresh: 2; url=index.php?au=send_message");
        $i++;
    }
}
else
{
?>
<table align='center'>
    <form method='post' action=''>
        <tr><td>Subject:</td><td><input type='text' name='subject' id='subject' value='' /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Message: </td><td><textarea name='message' id='home_text' cols='50' rows='15'></textarea></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='Send Message' /></td></tr>
    </form>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
```

When using the script with Xampp it produced the correct information and would echo out that it sent the emails out, even though it wasn't actually sending them, it means that it was working right. So I may be missing something in my PHP set up, but I would have no idea what.

So my question is, is there a better way to replicate `mysql_result` than what I am using for `mysqli` or am I missing something in the current function that I have here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fetch each row from the resource.  Like this:

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT `email` FROM `members` WHERE `alert` = '1'");
$num = $result->num_rows;

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())  //  <-------------here's how to get the data
{
    $email = $row'[email'];
    mail($email, $subject, $message, "From: ".$settings_info['website_name']." Admin<".$settings_info['admin_email'].">");
    echo "Email sent to: ".$email."<br />";
    header("Refresh: 2; url=index.php?au=send_message");

}
```

Comment: I was really hoping it would work! But it gives an error `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object` I figured it was going to because `mysqli` functions always want to be a pain in my butt.

Comment: @kira423: If `$result` is a non-object, that means your query is failing.

Comment: And it was because i mislabeled one of my row names -_- ty dnagirl

Answer (score 1):

> So as we know there is no actual mysqli result as there is with mysql

Who said you that? There is. Especially if you are using plain query(), not prepare()/execute():

```
// here goes your mysqli result:
$result = $db->query($query);
//now you can iterate over it getting row data
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $email = $row["email"];
    ...
}
```

please note that you are sending as many "Refresh" headers as many emails were sent.

> So I may be missing something in my PHP set up, but I would have no idea what.

Not in the PHP setup but rather in the code.
As you're using raw API functions in your code (which is disgusting to my taste), always run your queries at least this way

```
$result = $db->query($query) or trigger_error($db->error." [$query]");
```

and you'll be told what's wrong with yopr code or server or anything related to the failed query

Comment: Not sure why removing 1 extra line of coding is disgusting but we all do it different, but thank you for pointing out that I had my `header refresh` inside of my `while` loop